# How do I import an SVG to a class-based child-component in React?

Tags: reactjs, image, import, parent-child

I am able to import the svg in the parent component App.js(in the src folder) but not in the child component Home.js(src/components/Home.js)

When I import directly into the parent component the svg displays perfectly but if I import in the child component it says

Module not found: Can't resolve './img/BulbOn.svg' in 'E:\Website Work\Current Work\parsa_ventures\src\components'

```
   import './App.css'
   import Home from './components/Home'
   function App() {
     return (
        <div>
            <Home />
        </div>
    )
   }

   export default App
```

```
   import BulbOn from './img/BulbOn.svg'

   class Home extends React.Component {
     render() {
         return (
            <div>
                <img src={BulbOn} alt="text" />
            </div>
         )
     }
   }

   export default Home
```

I am new to react so I am wondering if I can easily import svg in child component without having to use props.

my folder structure paths,

Website `Work/Current Work/parsa_ventures/src/App.js` (Parent)
Website `Work/Current Work parsa_ventures/src/components/Home.js` (Child) Website `Work/Current Work/parsa_ventures/src/img/BulbOn.svg` (Image)
i put the react boilerplate inside parsa_ventures, so thats where the src is containing all the files

Comment: are you sure you are giving a proper path to that SVG file?

Comment: i literally copy pasted the path. works in parent doesnt work in child the same exact path

Comment: can you tell me the paths of your parent component and this child component?

Comment: as this will try to find this file at `Work/Current Work/parsa_ventures/src/components/img/BulbOn.svg`.

Comment: put the code of parent where it works

Comment: Website Work/Current Work/parsa_ventures/src/App.js (Parent)
Website Work/Current Work parsa_ventures/src/components/Home.js (Child)
Website Work/Current Work/parsa_ventures/src/img/BulbOn.svg (Image)


i put the react boilerplate inside parsa_ventures so thats where the src is containing all the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `./img` which means `E:\Website Work\Current Work\parsa_ventures\src\components\img\BulbOn.svg` should exist.
please check your paths,

you need to put `./../img/BulbOn.svg` should work.
try below code,

```
import BulbOn from './../img/BulbOn.svg'

   class Home extends React.Component {
     render() {
         return (
            <div>
                <img src={BulbOn} alt="text" />
            </div>
         )
     }
   }

   export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your path from the child component as it seems you have missed one folder and then try. 
Also, you can pass the svg image from parent to child component.

```
import React from 'react';
import Logo from '../../logo.svg';

class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img src={this.props.url} alt="text" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Test
```

In parent component, pass svg path url to child component - Test.

```
<Test url={Logo} />
```